# How can I transtlate this SQL to a Django database request?

Tags: python, sql, django

```
select * from first_table as ft, second_table as st where ft.user_id = st.user_id
```

The above sql has two tables that have the same column named "user_id" - I"d like to get the results of joining both tables but unsure how to translate the sql I know into something Django would recognise.

Edit: (some more info) There is a users table, the id of which is stored as a foreign key in both first_table and second_table as user_id. I'd like to join first_table and second_table based on user_id without having to query the users table.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using JOIN syntax. Any ideas on how to convert what I'm trying to do above but in a format Django would understand?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your models. How are your ForeignKeys defined?

Comment: There is a users table, the id of which is stored as a foreign key in both first_table and second_table as user_id. I'd like to join first_table and second_table based on user_id without having to query the users table.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the first_table rows that have the same user_id in second_table (a join)

sec= SecondTable.objects.all()
queryset = FirstTable.objects.filter(user_id__in=psobjs.values('sec'))

now if you want the data of FirstTable and SecondTable you might want to rethink your model again